# Mapping between simple class and class with inheritance

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have two classes like:

```
public class FileDto {
  private String name;
  private Integer size;
  private FileType fileType;
}
```

The second one is:

```
public class File extends AbstractFile {
  private String name;
  private Integer size;
}
```

Where

```
public class AbstractFile {
private FileConfiguration fileConfiguration;
}
```

And `FileConfiguration` has `FileType`:

```
public class FileConfiguration {
FileType fileType
}
```

Now I need to write three mappers using MapStruct:

The first one is easy and works fine - mapping from `File` to `FileDto`:

```
@Mapping(target = "fileType", source = "fileConfiguration.fileType")
  FileDto fromEntityToDto(final File entity);
```

The second one is from `FileDto` to `File`. I would like to try something like:

```
  @Mapping(target = "fileConfiguration.fileType", source = "fileType")
  File fromDtoToEntity(final FileDto dto);
```

But it give me an error:

```
error: incompatible types: FileConfigurationBuilder cannot be converted to FileConfiguration
            target.setFileConfiguration( FileConfiguration.builder() );
```

And the third is:

```
  @Mapping(target = "fileConfiguration.fileType", source = "fileType")
  File updateEntity(final FileDto dto, @MappingTarget final File target);
```

Could you tell me how can I put property `target` in `@Mapping` annotation? Or is there any other way?

Comment: I guess, you use a framework like Lombok?

Comment: Do you have a setter in AbstractFile using a FileConfiguration.Builder as parameter? If so, mapstruct does not know how to prepare the code. Can you include all getters/setter of your classes?